# Finding a pour point in a polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, snapping, watershed

I have a polygon shapefile (created by someone else) that is a bunch of little watersheds. Unfortunately, it doesn't include any coordinates in the attribute table for the lat/long of the pour point of said watersheds.

Is there a way to batch process roughly 1300 polygons to find the coordinates of the pour point of each polygon or is this just not possible?

Comment: This is probably a topic to take up with the data provider, though I must admit I've never thought of a watershed as having a single pour point,

Comment: Run an intersect with your river network and catchment polygons, the pour point will be the intersection point. This approach does assume you don't have network oddities like streams connecting across catchment boundaries in their upper reaches.

Comment: @Hornbydd judging by the total number of catchment it is a set of subcatchments belonging to one or few river networks. If this the case you suggestion will work for first few upstream  only. Others will have multiple intersection points.